# Insert a Row with values from multiple tables (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, row

I'm defining a delete trigger, and I need to backup the row deleted but only a few arguments from the original and including one column from other table:
TableC:
* Column 1: value from a column in TableA
* Column 2 to 6: values from colums 1,2,3,5,6 from TableB

All I want is something like this:

`INSERT into TableC values (

        (SELECT Column1A from TableA where TableA.Column = 'SomeValue'),

        (SELECT column1, column2, column3, column5, column6 from TableB));`

The result on TableC must be:
Column1A , column1, column2, column3, column5, column6

But that is not working.
In my special case, TableB is the deleted table accessible only in triggers.

I'm using SQL-Server 2008 but all I need is the logic of the query, and then I try to translate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In another case, which I honestly find very odd, that might be closer to what you're describing, this might work:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT 
    (SELECT ColumnA FROM Table1),
    Table2.ColumnA,
    Table2.ColumnB,
    Table2.ColumnC,
    Table2.ColumnD
FROM
    Table2
```

That way, you're only selecting that one column from `Table1`, yet selecting many columns from `Table2`, regardless of any relationship between them.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you for the fast answer.

Comment: Obviously this breaks if `Table1` returns more than one row; so you have to make sure you only run it under this very unique condition.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. But that's the exactly case here :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do joins on the select.
Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT 
    Table1.ColumnA,
    Table1.ColumnB,
    Table2.ColumnA,
    Table2.ColumnB
FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

This is just an example of "inserting from two tables".
You need to modify it to match what you're looking for, which I did not comprehend from your arbitrary example.

Comment: That's correct but both tables aren't related!
The First table only contains an index, and the Second, the values...

Comment: I'll keep this answer for anyone else's reference; check my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cross join` to join unrelated tables:

```
INSERT  MyTable
        (col5, col7)
SELECT  t1.col5
,       t2.col7
FROM    Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN 
        Table2 t2
WHERE   t1.ID = 'SomeValue'
        and t2.ID = 'OtherValue'
```

If one of the tables just contains one row, you can omit the `where` part for it.

Comment: I did in the way that Beemer said. I didn't understand this way :(. But Thank you anyways for the fast answer!